# Access 2010 Tab form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a tab form with several tabs. when I click on some of the tabs the page opens with the tabs at the top so I can click on another one. However, when I click on other tabs the page seems to scrol of focus down farther on the page and I have to scroll up to see the tabs.

Comment: Could you explain and define your problem a little better? Have you tried making the tab control smaller so that it all fits inside the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the whole tab control and pages within fit on screen at the resolution of your monitor. If you don't access will "scroll" down making it impossible to select your tabs even though you may have set the Can Shrink or Can Grow option to no.

Make the table control box smaller and see what happens. (to test if this is the issue you can alternative hide the menu bar of access while viewing your datatbase. This made me realize that my size was off by just a few pixels on my mine)